# Is it possible to set a process's command name (p_comm)?

Tags: macos, process, sysctl

iTerm2 on OS X sets the tab title based on the active process's command name, as given by `kp.kp_proc.p_comm` from the `kinfo_proc` structure (see https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/5f615f2cbd99d0ecf05e947b0395f36822c78da7/sources/ProcessCache.m#L132).

Is it possible for a process to set this on itself once it is running?

I tried a simple C program using `sysctl` to do it but I got the error "Operation not permitted" when trying to set the `kinfo_proc` on `"kern.proc.pid"` for my process's PID (even when using `sudo`). My C is not so great, so it's possible I was doing something wrong (I can paste the code here if you think that will help).

Is it possible to set the p_comm value for a process?